# Как использовать glm::ortho?

Tags: c++, opengl

Хочу получить результат, как, например, в Blender, в ортогональном режиме
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но нормально работает только обычная матрица проекции

```
projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(70.0f), (float)res[1] / (float)res[0], 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

При попытках использования ортогональной матрицы, просто ничего не отображается

```
projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)res[0], 0.0f, (float)res[1], 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

Находил в интернете разные варианты использования glm::ortho (аргументы в другом порядке), но ничего не помогло.

Что может быть не так?

Ниже код рендера и вершинный шейдер.

```
void renderScene()
{
    glm::mat4 view;
    glm::mat4 projection;

    view = activeCamera->getViewMatrix();
    //projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(70.0f), (float)res[1] / (float)res[0], 0.1f, 100.0f);
    projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)res[0], 0.0f, (float)res[1], 0.1f, 100.0f);
    unsigned int ID = shaders[0]->ID;

    glUseProgram(ID);
    for (unsigned int _m = 0; _m < models_size; _m++)
    {
        Model *_model = models[_m];
        Mesh *_mesh = _model->mesh;

        glm::mat4 model;
        model = glm::translate(model, *_model->position);
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(_model->scale->x, _model->scale->y, _model->scale->z));

        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(_model->rotation->x), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(_model->rotation->y), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(_model->rotation->z), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        glUseProgram(ID);
        glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, "viewPos"), 1, &activeCamera->position[0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, &projection[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);

        //for (int i = 0; i < _material->sizes.tex; i++) // Activating each texture of material
        //{
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
        const char *name = "myTex"; // uniform name
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name), 0); // shaderID, tex uniform name
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId); // tex id
        //}

        glBindVertexArray(_mesh->VAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _mesh->EBO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _mesh->indicesNum, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    }
}
```

========================================

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoords;

out vec2 TexCoords;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;  
    TexCoords = aTexCoords;
    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте `glm::ortho(-1.0f, 1.0, -1.0f * (float)res[1] / (float)res[0], 1.0f * (float)res[1] / (float)res[0], 0.1f, 100.0f);`. Если сработает — напишу развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: @Arhad, да, это работает (только я поменял местами res[1] и res[0], изображение было растянуто). Большое спасибо!

Comment: Ответ опубликовал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Изображение отсутствует из-за неправильно выставленной области проекции.

Вы задали её координаты в предположении, что экран покрывает область `(0; 0) –
(w; h)`. На самом же деле OpenGL отображает участок `(-1; 1) – (1; −1)`, деформируя его при неквадратных пропорциях области вывода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sup>*Источник: [OpenGL | Android Developers](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)*</sup>

Иными словами, область, реально выводимая на экран, находится где-то в левом верхнем углу вашей проекции, занимая её сотую или даже тысячную часть по каждой из осей.

Для расчёта правильных параметров `glm::ortho()` надо выполнить два шага:

1. Задать область проекции равной области вывода:

   ```
   glm::ortho(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
              ^^^^^  ^^^^  ^^^^^  ^^^^
   ```
2. Учесть пропорции экрана. Без этого изображение будет растянутым из-за вышеупомянутой деформации. Чтобы этого не было, мы сжимаем ось *x* настолько, насколько OpenGL её потом растянет:

   ```
   const float aspect = (float)res[0] / (float)res[1];
   projection = glm::ortho(-1.0f, 1.0, -1.0f * aspect, 1.0f * aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);
                                               ^^^^^^         ^^^^^^
   ```

И ещё. Так как в прямоугольной проекции нет такого понятия, как угол обзора, охват сцены можно менять исключительно масштабированием видимой части сцены:

```
const float n = ...;
projection = glm::ortho(-n, n, -n * aspect, n * aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);
                        ^^  ^  ^^           ^
```

Comment: А как в таком случае определять "ширину" проекции?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Вы про коэффициент растягивания? Ну так масштабируем прямоугольник экрана, чтобы высота равнялась единице, и получившаяся после масштабирования ширина — это и есть коэффициент предрастяжения. Говоря математически: берём размеры, делим на высоту и берём получившуюся масштабированную ширину, которая и становится тем самым  коэффициентом «расплющивания» (`a = w / h`).  Ну и заодно так совпало, что это, по сути, пропорции экрана (отчего и название «aspect (ratio)»).

Comment: Нет, это я понимаю. Я про то, что у ортографической проекции можно регулировать "ширину/высоту обзора" (не знаю, как правильно назвать; аналог угла обзора у перспективной проекции), домножая первые 4 параметре на `n`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а, понял. Ну, этот `n` и будет определять, во сколько раз больше (`n < 1`) или меньше (`n > 1`) влезет в кадр по сравнению со стандартной камерой. Так как проекция параллельная, то мы только масштаб менять и можем. Или опять неправильно понял?

Comment: Все правильно поняли. Это был тонкий намек, что в ответе про это не написано. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну, автор вопроса подобным не интересовался. Как бы то ни было, добавил абзац про это.